# Getting not enough memory error when installing CentOS

Tags: linux, memory, centos

Ok its been a long time since working with Linux, first time with CentOS (Worked with Redhat when it was free, before it went to Fedora). Anyway I have an old HP DC5000 computer with 256GB of memory and a 250GB IDE hard drive. I am trying to install version 6.8, version 7 goes into kernel panic mode for some reason. When I select the option to install with basic graphic drivers I get the error that I do not have enough memory to install CentOS.

Is 256GB not enough? I just want to install it to access the command line as this will be my local server. Is there any way around this?

Comment: per [About Wiki page](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product) - 392M CLI/512M GUI per logical CPU

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to 256MB for your old HP. Still with that memory probably only console install is allowed.